# Predicting the location where new health centres should be built using R,Machine Learning

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have the geolocation of health centres in Ireland mapped in Tableau and I am looking to try to implement a machine learning aspect to this project where new health centre locations are predicted in order to show where new health centres should be placed in the future in order to provide better health services in the country(in rural areas etc.).

I have population data and the boundaries for this project would be counties, each county can have multiple HC's.

I am unsure how to go about this and I am looking for advice as Im new to machine learning. For example what Prediction Algorithm would best suit this task. Im also using RStudio to do this project.

**Here is an image of the current health centres:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did some work in the 1990's with Stan Openshaw at the University of Leeds looking at [location optimisation using spatial interaction models](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0024713) (using car dealers rather than health centres) which may get you started.

Stan also did a lot of work on [zone design](http://www.geog.leeds.ac.uk/papers/96-6/) in that period which may also help.

Don't be put off by the fact we were using supercomputers in those days, a modern PC should handle the load just fine now.